Cubic custom ISO which executes shell script at startup not working
I have tried this steps but not working

First I have create a simple script in /opt/test.sh
Then give execute permission for that file
Create a test.desktop file in the following location /etc/xdg/autostart
Generate a new ISO.
Then I have install that iso on my VM the file not created as I wrote in the script file.

test.sh
#!/bin/bash

touch /opt/filecreated

test.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/test.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Test File
Name=Test File
Comment[en_US]=Test File
Comment=Test File

Please help me to run a script file when install iso
Thank you
